# Filter out common entries from two sequences, returning two lists with unique entries from the originals

Tags: scala, sequences

I want to filter the common elements out of two lists, and get left with two lists containing the remainders.

I have two sequences in scala:

```
val firstSeq = Seq(1,2,3,4)
val secondSeq = Seq(1,3,5,7)
```

And what I want to do is filter all of the common elements, which would mean I end up with:

```
filteredFirstSeq = Seq(2,4)
filteredSecondSeq = Seq(5,7)
```

So, there's an easy way to get here in scala:

```
val filteredFirstSeq = firstSeq.filterNot(firstEntry => secondSeq.contains(firstEntry))
val filteredSecondSeq = secondSeq.filterNot(secondEntry => firstSeq.contains(secondEntry))
```

But! This means I have to run through the entire first list, and matches, *and* the entire second list, and matches, which takes a long time when the lists are large, and the entries are more complicated than integers!

I'd much prefer to only have to cycle through everything once, but the only way I can think to do so is to have mutable lists, and remove a value from both whenever we find a match. That seems a bit nasty, though. I'm certain that there must be a trivial answer to this that I'm missing.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Are the lists guaranteed to my unique?  For example, will there be duplicates in the individual lists?

Comment: There's a much more concise method to get what you want: `firstSeq diff secondSeq` and its compliment `secondSeq diff firstSeq`. Unfortunately it is not, obviously, a single traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example assumes that the each of the lists contains no duplicates, if that is not the case then the logic inside of the fold will have to change slightly.

```
val firstSeq = Seq(1,2,3,4)
val secondSeq = Seq(1,3,5,7)

// Put everything into a list, keeping track of where things came from
val both: Seq[(Int, Int)] = firstSeq.map(x => (x, 1)) ++ secondSeq.map(x => (x, 2))

// Reduce the list into a single map, where the keys are the numbers, and the value is the originating seq.  Anytime we try to insert a value that already is in the map, we remove the value instead, since that will mean the value was in each sequence.
val map: Map[Int, Int] = both.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Int]) { (map, tuple) =>
  val (value, seqNumber) = tuple
  if (map.contains(value)) {
    map - value
  } else {
    map + (value -> seqNumber)
  }
}

// Now partition the values back into their original lists
val (firstSeqFiltered, secondSeqFiltered) = map.partition(_._2 == 1)
println(firstSeqFiltered.keys)
println(secondSeqFiltered.keys)
```

Output:

```
Set(2, 4)
Set(5, 7)
```